# Infinite Union of Complete Metric Subspaces which is Not Complete

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Can anyone think of an example of a metric space $(X,d)$ and an infinite set of complete metric subspaces in $(X,d)$ such that their union is not complete?

Comment: How do you define the metric on the union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the space $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric. Consider the subspaces $X_n = \{ 1/n \}$ which are obviously complete with respect to the induced topology.

Do you think however that the union of the $X_n$ (for $n \geq 1$), as a subspace of $\Bbb R$, is complete (with respect to the induced topology)?